# Resultset into 2d array

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, resultset

I just did a mysql query, which was put into a resultset called result.

Now i want it to go into a 2d object, which i can use to show the query result later on.

I am not quite sure how to do it, if i should make a while loop and then put into an array.
I have tested that there is something in the result by out.write it to a txt file.

```
ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

Here is what i got, i tried:

```
int i =0;
        sqlresult = new String[result.getMetaData().getColumnCount()];
        while(result.next()){
            sqlresult[i] = result.getArray(sql);
            i++;
        }
```

But this i keep getting an error, and its only 1d array.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should give you a 2-dimensional data structure, as a List, containing as many elements as there are rows in the result set, with String values for each column value in the row.

```
int nCol = result.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
List<String[]> table = new ArrayList<>();
while( result.next()) {
    String[] row = new String[nCol];
    for( int iCol = 1; iCol <= nCol; iCol++ ){
            Object obj = result.getObject( iCol );
            row[iCol-1] = (obj == null) ?null:obj.toString();
    }
    table.add( row );
}

// print result
for( String[] row: table ){
    for( String s: row ){
        System.out.print( " " + s );
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: I dont know why, but when i try this i get the references into the array table. so when i sysout it, i get something like [Ljava.lang.String;@6487d5bd, .. Any things i do wrong?

Comment: That's to be expected. You'll have to write a wee loop to print the rows one by one.

Comment: Thanks.. yeah i forgot i had to loop when its 2darray :)

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you want but this code will get the column value from the current resultset and store it in an array.

```
         while(result.next()){
             java.sql.Array columnVar = rs.getArray("ColumnName");
             String[] zips = (String[])columnVar.getArray();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

This converts the whole resultset into a 2d array of Objects.

```
        Object[][] resultSet = new Object[rows][columns];
        int row = 0;
        while (result.next()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
                resultSet[row][i] = result.getObject(i+1);
            }
            row++;
        }
```

Comment: This assumes you know the row count, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in simple way as:

```
ResultSetMetaData metadata = Result.getMetaData();
numberOfColumns = metadata.getColumnCount();
ResultSetArray= new String[numberOfRows][numberOfColumns];
int i=0;
while (Result.next()) {

    for (int j = 0; j < numberOfColumns; j++) {
        ResultSetArray[i][j] = Result.getString(j+1);
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.